# A Covariant Tuple

Tags: c#, .net, covariance

I was searching for a way to put a `Tuple<List>` into a `Tuple<IEnumerable>`, and I found that Tuple has no covariance.

1. [Is C# 4.0 Tuple covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872867/is-c-sharp-4-0-tuple-covariant)
2. [Co/Contravariance? Tuple> not satisfied with List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437845/co-contravariance-tuplestring-ienumerablestring-not-satisfied-with-listst)

I decide to make my own implementation of an interface which subclass a tuple with a support for Covariance:

```
/// <summary>
/// A wrapper around Tuple for gaining covariance
/// </summary>
public static class ITuple
{
    private class _ITuple<T1> : Tuple<T1>, ITuple<T1> { public _ITuple(T1 item1) : base(item1) { } }
    public static ITuple<T1> Create<T1>(T1 item1) { return new _ITuple<T1>(item1); }

    private class _ITuple<T1, T2> : Tuple<T1, T2>, ITuple<T1, T2> { public _ITuple(T1 item1, T2 item2) : base(item1, item2) { } }
    public static ITuple<T1, T2> Create<T1, T2>(T1 item1, T2 item2) { return new _ITuple<T1, T2>(item1, item2); }

    private class _ITuple<T1, T2, T3> : Tuple<T1, T2, T3>, ITuple<T1, T2, T3> { public _ITuple(T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3) : base(item1, item2, item3) { } }
    public static ITuple<T1, T2, T3> Create<T1, T2, T3>(T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3) { return new _ITuple<T1, T2, T3>(item1, item2, item3); }
}

public interface ITuple<out T1> { T1 Item1 { get; } }
public interface ITuple<out T1, out T2> { T1 Item1 { get; } T2 Item2 { get; } }
public interface ITuple<out T1, out T2, out T3> { T1 Item1 { get; } T2 Item2 { get; } T3 Item3 { get; } }
```

Some tests and usage:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestCompile()
{
    // no assertion, just test that the compilation work
    ITuple<Exception> item = ITuple.Create<NullReferenceException>(null);
    ITuple<IEnumerable<int>> item2 = ITuple.Create<List<int>>(null);
}
[TestMethod]
public void TestEqual()
{
    Assert.AreEqual(ITuple.Create(1, Tuple.Create("a")), ITuple.Create(1, Tuple.Create("a")));
    Assert.AreNotEqual(ITuple.Create(1, Tuple.Create("a")), ITuple.Create(1, Tuple.Create("b")));
}
```

I choose to hide the implementation of the concrete class `_ITuple` inside the static class, so you have access only to the public and static builder `ITuple.Create`.

Problems:

1. **Subclass and equality support**

   Subclassing the tuple is easy and there is nothing to do, and this is my concern. Is there something am I missing? I see no reason why equalities and hashcode souldn't work as expected with classic Tuple, but maybe you will find a problem somewhere which I didn't think of.
2. **Naming convention**

   - Like the static class `Tuple` contains all the `Create` static methods, `ITuple`, which is not an interface, has the static builder. At what point is this weird to name a non interface with an `I` prefix?
   - At first, I called the `ITuple` interface `ICovariantTuple`, but found it too long, and there is no `ITuple` in the framework. Is this evident that `ITuple` is covariant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. I think that non-interface types shouldn't be called `ISomething`. You could just call the static class `Tuple` and differentiate it from `System.Tuple` by using a different namespace. Or you could call the class something like `TupleEx`, though that's not very descriptive.

   But the best option is if you could figure out a good name for the type that differentiates it from `System.Tuple`. I agree that `CovariantTuple` is quite long, though I don't have any better ideas.
2. I also don't like the name `_ITuple`, even if it's not publicly visible. I would call it something like `TupleImpl`. (Again, if you figure out a good name, you could use that here too.)
3. Regarding equality: your `ITuple`s will show as equal to normal `Tuple`s with the same contents. This most likely is what you want, but you should be aware of it.

   I don't think there are any other problems with equality or hash codes.
4. Consider not writing everything on a single line. I think it will make the code clearer.
5. It might make sense to add some way to convert `System.Tuple` to `ITuple` and back.

Comment: +1, points 1 and 5 possibly lead us to a `TupleFactory` with methods like `Create()` and `CreateCovariant()`?